# Pset5 Speller: I'm getting segmentation fault with small dictionary

Tags: c, cs50

When i used check50, my program was not giving any report as output. So i tried my code with small dictionary and i got a segmentation fault. I think it has do with my unload function
This is my code

```
// Implements a dictionary's functionality

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// Number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = 125;
int word_size = 0;

// Hash table
node *hashtable[N];

// Returns true if word is in dictionary else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    //Convert the word to lowercase
    int length = strlen(word);
    char copy[length + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        copy[i] = tolower(word[i]);
    }
    copy[length] = '\0';
    //Find out the hash value
    int hash_value = hash(copy);
    node *tmp = hashtable[hash_value];
    //Check if word is in dictionary
    while(tmp != NULL)
    {
        if(strcasecmp(tmp->word, copy) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    return false;
}

// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    //It's djb2 hash function
    unsigned int hash = 5381;
    int c;
    while ((c = *word++))
        hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c;
    return hash % N;
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    //Initialize all indexs of hastable to NULL
    for(int i =0; i < LENGTH + 1; i++)
    {
        hashtable[i] = NULL;
    }
    char word[LENGTH +1];
    int pos;
    FILE *dict = fopen(dictionary,"r");
    if(dict == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    //Scan every word...I think my problem is in here
    while (fscanf(dict, "%s", word) != EOF)
    {
        word_size++;
        int length = strlen(word);
        char copy[length + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            copy[i] = tolower(word[i]);
        }
        copy[length] = '\0';
        node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
        strcpy(new_node->word,copy);
        new_node->next = NULL;
        //Find the hash value
        pos = hash(copy);
        //Set the pointer of the new node to index of hashtable
        new_node->next = hashtable[pos];
        hashtable[pos] = new_node;
    }
    return true;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    return word_size;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful else false
bool unload(void)
{
    node *cursor = NULL;
    node* tmp = NULL;
    for(int i=0; i < N; i++)
    {
        while(cursor->next != NULL)
        {
            tmp = cursor;
            cursor = cursor->next;
            free(tmp);
        }
        free(cursor);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Can anyone say the write logic if my unload function is wrong. It works fine with large dictionary. I tried but couldn't figure out how to use debug50

Comment: Which exact line of code triggers the seg fault? That info can be obtained instantly by running the program in a debugger and is the minimum debugging you should already have done. Then you can continue to use the debugger to trace the execution of the code to see what it is dong to help find the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `unload ()` function you soon define

```
node *cursor = NULL;
```

but then, without assigning to `cursor` any other value, you dereference it:

```
while ( cursor->next != NULL )
```

Dereferencing a NULL pointer raises undefined behavior, and it will likely result in a segmentation fault.

The following action is `free(cursor);` that, with a NULL pointer, is not good as well.